# How to use multiple filters in a MongoDb find query using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have this query which works fine in datagrip

```
test> db.getCollection("comments").find({status: {$ne: "APPROVED"},storyID: {$regex: "bbjfn-*"}})
```

I'm just wondering how to achieve the same thing in C# using the MongoDB Driver 2.13.1

```
IMongoDatabase database = MongoClient.GetDatabase(Program.Settings.MongoDB.Database);
IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("comments");

var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("status", new BsonDocument("$ne", "APPROVED")) & 
Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("storyID", new BsonDocument("$regex", "bbjfnfn-*"));

var results = await collection.FindAsync(filter);
```

Doesn't work.. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `filter` with `BsonDocument` object as below:

```cs
FilterDefinition<Store> filter = new BsonDocument
{
    { "status", new BsonDocument("$ne", "APPROVED") }, 
    { "storyID", new BsonDocument("$regex", "bbjfn-*") }
};
```

OR

```cs
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Ne("status", "APPROVED") & builder.Regex("storyID", "bbjfn-*");
```

FYI, you can use MongoDB Compass to [export Query to C# Language](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/export-query-to-language/).